# Angular2 Service variables being reset on route change

Tags: angular, service, angular2-routing

I have a service that i am using to keep track of the state of my model. I have multiple components that i would like to have access this service variables properties. When the first component loads on init, i set the model, yet when i try to access this model from my second component after route change, the variable is now undefined. Below is an example of what im talking about.

Component 1

```
constructor(private service: Service, private route)

ngOninit(){
  this.service.setModel();
  console.log(this.service.getModel()); <-- works fine
}

componentButton1Click(){
  route.navigateByUrl(component2route) <--works fine
}
```

Component 2

```
constructor(private service: Service)

ngOninit(){
  console.log(this.service.index); <-- undefined
}
```

Service

```
private index: number;

constructor(private http: Http)

getModel(){
   return this.index; <-- works fine
}

setModel(){
  this.index = this.http.get('somejsonfile.json').index;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common cause of this issue is that the service is registered more than one time. Check the contents of the `providers` array in each of your components and modules and ensure that it is only registered in *ONE* place.

Here is a code snippet:

```
  providers: [
    ProductService,
    ProductGuardService
  ]
```

These are part of the `@Component` or `@NgModule` metadata

Comment: this was it! I had the service globally and had it in multiple module providers, so i took it out of everything and just put it in the app.module.

Comment: will accept the answer in a few minutes when i am able to