# Singleton Service Resets After Route Change

Tags: angular, angular7

## The Setup

I have a singleton service, `GlobalSearchService`, that I am loading and providing in `AppModule`. This is the only place that a provider is specified for this service, and the only module into which it is imported.

## The Desired Result

I've done this in the hope that `GlobalSearchService` will act as a global singleton, accessible to all components which load it and declare it in their constructor.

## The Actual Result

The singleton service does exactly like I have described above, unless and until the route is changed. Anytime the route changes the service resets to its initial state with no data.

## The Fix?

I'm looking for a way to ensure that this global singleton maintains its state regardless of any actions other than destructive browsers actions (such as reload/refresh, etc).

## What I've tried

I've tried setting up `forRoot`, although I could have done it incorrectly as my knowledge of `forRoot` is limited. I also ensured that `providedIn` is set to `'root'` in the actual service. Right now I have the app component resetting the state on every route change since the service caches its state anyways, but I feel like that's not the right way to go about this.

Comment: How have you imported the service in the rest of your components?

Comment: Without any code examples its really hard to help, maybe set up an example on Stackblitz?

Comment: The service is imported into, but not provided in, every component that needs access to the data that exists in the search service.

Comment: @Malcor I'm not sure what I would set up for an example, it's just a singleton service that's part of the `AppModule` that gets reset on route change. If you give me some direction on what you are looking for I'd be happy to set up an example for you.

Comment: I asked how exactly you imported the service, not where. Has it been declared as a provider in your Module.ts file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 Service variables being reset on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824330/angular2-service-variables-being-reset-on-route-change)

Comment: I've set up an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ls8zg), as you can see by clicking the `second component` link, the data between the service is persisted. If you manually navigate to `/second` from the url, your state is reset.